# Extend Tomcat manager app access through external file

Tags: java, tomcat

We have access to the tomcat manager app restricted by authentication and IP address. See example config:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/server/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="{some-ips}"/>

  <!-- Link to the user database we will get roles from -->
  <ResourceLink name="users" global="UserDatabase"
                type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

</Context>
```

Is there any way to reference an additional file on the local machine that determines additional IP addresses that are allowed to access the manager app?

Thanks.